# Unable to create node in jenkins2.0

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-agent

I have installed Jenkins2.0 version and created node. But after save when I try to configure the created node, Jenkins is not opening the node configuration.

All other tabs are working but related to specific node I am unable to perform any operations.

I have faced similar issue today morning but I have reinstalled Jenkins that resolved the above issue but facing this again.

Any inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downgrading the Credentials plugin back, from 2.0 to 1.28. I faced similar issue when I updated this plugin and downgrading solved it.